# android to add comma for the numbers which are in String

Tags: android, json, string, number-formatting

I'm getting a string from Json response as follows:

"Your account balance is 100000 as on Monday"

In this I need to add comma to the numerical value. Can anyone please help me how I can add this.Thanks in advance.

In this case, I would like to have the output in the following format:

"Your account balance is 100,000 as on Monday"

Comment: Can you add your desired output ??

Comment: you mean like this: `100,000`?

Comment: What do you want exactly?

Comment: Take a look at this [SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29778775/how-to-add-empty-space-inside-int/29778914#29778914).

Answer (score 3):

```
NumberFormat anotherFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US);
if (anotherFormat instanceof DecimalFormat) {
    DecimalFormat anotherDFormat = (DecimalFormat) anotherFormat;
    anotherDFormat.applyPattern("#.00");
    anotherDFormat.setGroupingUsed(true);
    anotherDFormat.setGroupingSize(3);

    for (double d : numbers) {
        System.out.println(anotherDFormat.format(d));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final String jsonString = "Your account balance is 100000 as on Monday";

DecimalFormat decFormat = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US);
decFormat.setGroupingUsed(true);
decFormat.setGroupingSize(3);

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(jsonString);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(decFormat.format(Double.valueOf(m.group())));
}
```